# How to access nested structure variables

Tags: c++

I have an structure AVFilter,

```
typedef struct AVFilter 
{

const char *name;  
const char *description;  
const AVClass *priv_class;  
int priv_size;  
int (*init)(AVFilterContext *ctx);  
void (*uninit)(AVFilterContext *ctx);  
int (*query_formats)(AVFilterContext *);  
const AVFilterPad *inputs;  
const AVFilterPad *outputs;  
int (*process_command)(AVFilterContext *, const char *cmd, const char *arg, char *res, int res_len, int flags);  
}  AVFilter;
```

I am accessing sturctur variables like,

```
AVFilter avfilter_vsrc_color = {  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.name            = "color",  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.description     = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("Provide an uniformly colored input."),  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.priv_class      = &color_class,        // error here  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.priv_size       = sizeof(TestSourceContext),// error here  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.init            = color_init,// error here  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.uninit          = uninit,// error here  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.query_formats   = color_query_formats,// error here  
    avfilter_vsrc_color.inputs          = NULL,// error here
    avfilter_vsrc_color.outputs         = color_outputs,// error here
    avfilter_vsrc_color.process_command = color_process_command // error here  
};
```

I dont know how to access priv_class.Please help me to solve this issue

If i did like this,

```
AVFilter avfilter_vsrc_color=
{  
    .name            = "color",  //error
    .description     = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("Provide an uniformly colored input."),  
    .priv_class      = &color_class,  
    .priv_size       = sizeof(TestSourceContext),  
    .init            = color_init,  
    .uninit          = uninit,  
    .query_formats   = color_query_formats,  
    .inputs          = NULL,  
    .outputs         = color_outputs,  
    .process_command = color_process_command  
};
```

I m getting error like,

```
2>c:\users\awki6\desktop\ffmpeg\libavfilter\vsrc_testsrc.cpp(271): error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '.'  
2>c:\users\awki6\desktop\ffmpeg\libavfilter\vsrc_testsrc.cpp(271): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

Comment: What's the problem? What do you want to do to `priv_class`? What is `AVClass`?

Comment: AVClass is a another structure and priv_class is a pointer to AVCLass.

Comment: I know that. And I have found the definition of `AVClass` in one of your other questions. You haven't answered my other questions. You seem to be using commas where you should use semicolons. You are still posting error messages without telling us which lines correspond to the line numbers. You have edited the question to refer to `color_class` without explaining what that is. You seem to be attempting to run before you can walk. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

```
AVFilter avfilter_vsrc_color=
{  
     "color", 
     NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("Provide an uniformly colored input."),  
     &color_class, 
     ...
};
```

or more verbose but maybe also more readable (as you have many fields):

```
AVFilter avfilter_vsrc_color;
avfilter_vsrc_color.name = color;
avfilter_vsrc_color.description = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("Provide an uniformly colored input.");
avfilter_vsrc_color.priv_class = &color_class;
...
```

Comment: That is not the issue OP has, and the way he is initializing is perfectly legal.

Comment: Whether it's accepted depends on the compiler though. g++ 4.2.1 "error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token"; clang 3.2: compiles

Comment: Just realized it is in C standard but not C++. g++ support it by using gnu extension flag btw.